# Clone of an undirected graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, reinventing-the-wheel

Perform a graph clone. Verifying complexity to be O(E). Looking for code review, optimizations and best practices.

```
class NodeOfGraph<T> {
    private final T item;

    NodeOfGraph(T item) { 
        this.item = item;
    }

    public T getItem() {
        return item;
    }
}

public class GraphWithCloneFunctionality<T> implements Iterable<NodeOfGraph<T>> {

    /*
     *  A map from nodes in the graph to list of outgoing edges. 
     */
    private final Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double>> graph;

    public GraphWithCloneFunctionality() {
        graph = new HashMap<NodeOfGraph<T>,  Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double>>();
    }

    public GraphWithCloneFunctionality(Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double>> graph) {
        if (graph == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The graph should not be null");
        }
        this.graph = graph;
    }

    /**
     *  Adds a new node to the graph. If the node already exists then its a
     *  no-op.
     * 
     * @param node  Adds to a graph. If node is null then this is a no-op.
     * @return      true if node is added, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean addNode(NodeOfGraph<T> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The input node cannot be null.");
        }
        graph.put(node, new HashMap<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double>());
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Given the two nodes it would add an arc from source 
     * to destination node. 
     *  
     * @param node1                     the node1 node.
     * @param node2                     the node2 node.
     * @param length                    if length if string 
     * @throws NullPointerException     if node1 or nod2 is null.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException   if either node1 or node2 does not exists. 
     */ 
    public void addEdge (NodeOfGraph<T> node1, NodeOfGraph<T> node2, double length) { 
        if (node1 == null || node2 == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("node1 and node2, both should be non-null.");
        }
        if (!graph.containsKey(node1) || !graph.containsKey(node2)) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("node1 and node2, both should be part of graph");
        }
        graph.get(node1).put(node2, length);
        graph.get(node2).put(node1, length);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<NodeOfGraph<T>> iterator() {
        return graph.keySet().iterator();
    }    

    /**
     * Given a node, returns the edges going outward that node,
     * as an immutable map.
     * 
     * @param node The node whose edges should be queried.
     * @return An immutable view of the edges leaving that node.
     * @throws NullPointerException   If input node is null.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException If node is not in graph.
     */
    public Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double> edgesFrom(NodeOfGraph<T> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The node should not be null.");
        }
        final Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double> edges = graph.get(node);
        if (edges == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Source node does not exist.");
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(edges);
    }

    /**
     * Clones the graph. Performs deep copy.
     */
    public GraphWithCloneFunctionality<T> clone() {
        final Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double>> clonedGraph = new HashMap<NodeOfGraph<T>, Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double>>();
        final Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, NodeOfGraph<T>> cloneMap = new HashMap<NodeOfGraph<T>, NodeOfGraph<T>>();

        for (NodeOfGraph<T> node : graph.keySet()) {
            NodeOfGraph<T> clonedNode = new NodeOfGraph<T>(node.getItem());
            clonedGraph.put(clonedNode, new HashMap<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double>());
            cloneMap.put(node, clonedNode);
        }

        for (Entry<NodeOfGraph<T>, Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double>>  entry : graph.entrySet())  {
            NodeOfGraph<T> source = entry.getKey();
            NodeOfGraph<T> sourceClone = cloneMap.get(source);
            Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double> edges = entry.getValue();

            for (Entry<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double> edge  : edges.entrySet()) {
                NodeOfGraph<T> destination = edge.getKey();
                NodeOfGraph<T> destinationClone = cloneMap.get(destination);
                clonedGraph.get(sourceClone).put(destinationClone, edge.getValue());
            }
        }
        return new GraphWithCloneFunctionality<T>(clonedGraph);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GraphWithCloneFunctionality<Integer> graph = new GraphWithCloneFunctionality<Integer>();
        NodeOfGraph<Integer> nodeA = new NodeOfGraph<Integer>(1);
        NodeOfGraph<Integer> nodeB = new NodeOfGraph<Integer>(2);
        NodeOfGraph<Integer> nodeC = new NodeOfGraph<Integer>(3);

        graph.addNode(nodeA);
        graph.addNode(nodeB);
        graph.addNode(nodeC);

        graph.addEdge(nodeA, nodeB, 10);
        graph.addEdge(nodeB, nodeC, 20);

        GraphWithCloneFunctionality<Integer> graphClone = graph.clone();


        for (NodeOfGraph<Integer> node : graphClone) {
            System.out.print("Node-> " + node.getItem() + " Edges-> ");
            for (Entry<NodeOfGraph<Integer>, Double> node1 : graphClone.edgesFrom(node).entrySet()) {
                System.out.print(" Node : " + node1.getKey().getItem() + " value : " + node1.getValue() + " , ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Clone is an ugly API. [Josh Bloch has a lot to say about it.](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

My opinion on it, is that you should use it as a last resort, and, when you do use it, it should be a short-cut to a public copy-constructor.

In other words, your clone method should look like:

```
public GraphWithCloneFunctionality<T> clone() {
    return new GraphWithCloneFunctionality<T>(this);
}
```

This way, you have the benefit of the Copy-Constructor, and the functionality of the clone as well, if needed.

After having said all that, I can't see any other significant issues in your code's functionality. It looks about right, and nice and clean.

If you create a copy-constructor, it would look something like:

```
public GraphWithCloneFunctionality(GraphWithCloneFunctionality<T> tocopy) {
    this(copyGraph(tocopy.graph));
}
```

The copyGraph function would copy the graph, believe it or not.

Talking about graph-copying, this constructor should take a defensive copy of the `graph` as well. You don't want to have leaks of graph functionality to outside your class...

> ```
> public GraphWithCloneFunctionality(Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Map<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double>> graph) {
>     if (graph == null) {
>         throw new NullPointerException("The graph should not be null");
>     }
>     this.graph = graph;
> }
> ```

The above `this.graph = graph` is not safe. Use `this.graph = copyGraph(graph);`

Comment: But I wanted deep-copy.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper You can do a deep-copy in the constructor just as easily as you do it in the clone.... also, added more detail to answer (submitted early by mistake).

Answer (score 3):

Your `clone()` method looks very nice, and I don't have much to say about it except Good Work.

I've read the code a few times, and even then I almost missed this:

```
/**
 *  Adds a new node to the graph. If the node already exists then its a
 *  no-op.
 * 
 * @param node  Adds to a graph. If node is null then this is a no-op.
 * @return      true if node is added, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean addNode(NodeOfGraph<T> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("The input node cannot be null.");
    }
    graph.put(node, new HashMap<NodeOfGraph<T>, Double>());
    return true;
}
```

The comment assures the caller that trying to add a node which already exists will be no-op and return false.
In actuality - it will override the existing node, deleting all out-going edges, and return true...

This is another example of how a good unit-test suite is a better documentation than comments.